# How to Retrieve png image from varbinary(max) SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, binary, base64, blob

I'm stuck in converting varbinary(MAX) from SQL Server to png image in php. I've been following tutorial like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>base 64</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$image_data = "0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4.....";
?>
<img width='900px' height='900px' src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(pack("H*",$image_data));?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KE6LTXzcOucCej32nU7L?p=preview)

But it's not working. Only a half of image is displayed. Not full image. Is there any difference data blob in mySql and SQL Server? Or it's all about size?